# Vue3 - Render query parameter

Tags: vue.js

I am quite new to Vue in general, especially Vue3. I have a route `/mypage` that takes one query parameter `id` such as `/mypage?id=hjhj`.

What I am trying to achieve is to render that query parameter on `/mypage?id=hjhj`

**router/index.js**

```js
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';
const history = isServer ? createMemoryHistory() : createWebHistory();
const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component: About,
    },
    {
        path: '/mypage',
        name: 'mypage',
        component: MyPage,
        props: (route) => ({
            foo: route.query.foo
        }),
    }
];

const router = createRouter({
    history,
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

**MyPage.vue**

```html
<template>
   <h2>Home</h2>
   <h3>{{ this.foo }}</h3>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
     props: {
       foo: {
         type: String,
         default: null,
       },
     },
   };
</script>
```

result:

[image]

I should see hjhj below "Home"

Comment: You could do something like https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching-with-params

Comment: Thanks but it seems that this documentation is for Path and there is nothing for Query parameters

Comment: Yes sorry. you can simply do this in the home template : `$route.query.id`

Comment: or in the setup method:

`import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    console.log(route.query.id);
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

In templates we don't use `this` keyword to access the instance properties, as every variable available in template is proxied to the component instance.

```html
<template>
   <h2>Home</h2>
   <h3>{{ foo }}</h3>
</template>
```